# Nombre alternativo a función

Tags: javascript

He creado dos funciones, pero **la relevante** para esta pregunta es la llamada `multipleNames()`

Suponiendo que tengo la funcion `$(s,e)` en donde me retorna similar a cuando realizo `$(".class")` o `$("#id")` con *Jquery*.

***El problema viene***, que **si se llamara a otra función(que en verdad no existiría) con alguno de los nombres que estan dentro del array**(el que está dentro de la función `multipleNames`), se llamará a la funcion `$(s,e)` , osea sería como un **seudónimo o un nombre alternativo**.

Osea si yo hiciera `selector("#", "miId")` , fuese lo mismo que hacerlo con el nombre original de la función `$("#", "miId")` , pero lo que NO quiero es volver a escribir toda la función y cambiarle solo el nombre, sino a una misma función agregarle multiples seudónimos, sin crear otras funciones.

Como por ejemplo(*Pseudocódigo*) :

```
function soyUnaFuncion(){
 return true;
}.addNickName("apodo1","alternativo","callMe");
```

```js
function $(s,e){ 
 return (s=="#") ? document.getElementById(e) : 
        (s==".") ? document.getElementsByClassName(e) : 
        document.getElementsByTagName(e);
}


function multipleNames(){
var accepted = ["jQuery","selector","get"];
/* Pseudocódigo

if(accepted.includes(funcionLlamada)) {
 var s = parametro 's' de funcionLlamada()
 var e = parametro 'e' de funcionLlamada()
 $(s,e); // 

}

*/
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto lo puedes conseguir de una manera sencilla, haciendo una asignación múltiple de variables al definir la función:

```js
apodo1 = alternativo = callMe = soyUnaFuncion = function() {
 return true;
};

console.log(apodo1());
console.log(alternativo());
console.log(callMe());
console.log(soyUnaFuncion());
```

---

Si lo quieres hacer con una función, podrías definirla de tal manera que el primer argumento sea la función y, o bien tenga un segundo argumento con un array de nombres, o tenga argumentos indefinidos con los nombres.

Algo como esto:

```js
function $(s,e){ 
  return (s=="#") ? document.getElementById(e) : 
         (s==".") ? document.getElementsByClassName(e) : 
         document.getElementsByTagName(e);
}

function multipleNames(){
  // el primer argumento es la función, el resto son otros nombres
  for (var x = 1; x < arguments.length; x++) {
    eval(arguments[x] + " = " + arguments[0]);
  }
}

multipleNames($, "jQuery", "selector", "get");

console.log($("#", "otroDiv"));
console.log(jQuery("#", "otroDiv"));
console.log(selector(".", "unDiv"));
console.log(get(".", "unDiv"));
```

```html
<div class="unDiv">Uno</div>
<div id="otroDiv">Dos</div>
```

O podrías usar el [operador de propagación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) (*spread operator*) del estándar ES6:

```js
function $(s,e){ 
  return (s=="#") ? document.getElementById(e) : 
         (s==".") ? document.getElementsByClassName(e) : 
         document.getElementsByTagName(e);
}

function multipleNames(func, ...nombres){
  // el primer argumento es la función, el resto son otros nombres
  for (var x = 0; x < nombres.length; x++) {
    eval(nombres[x] + " = " + func);
  }
}

multipleNames($, "jQuery", "selector", "get");

console.log($("#", "otroDiv"));
console.log(jQuery("#", "otroDiv"));
console.log(selector(".", "unDiv"));
console.log(get(".", "unDiv"));
```

```html
<div class="unDiv">Uno</div>
<div id="otroDiv">Dos</div>
```